# convert YYYYMMDD to date format YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to convert bigdecimal(YYYYMMDD) to date format (YYYY/MM/DD) using pig script. For that i have written below code

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/hl7' USING PigStorage('|');
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($1 matches '.*OBR.*');
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ToString($8,'yyyy-MM-dd')AS date;
```

Output i am getting is

```
20140926-01-01
20140929-01-01
20141002-01-01
```

Though the expected output is

```
2014/09/26
2014/09/29
2014/10/02
```

Sample is having date

```
20140926
20140929
20141002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ToString($8,'yyyy-MM-dd')AS date;
```

I wonder why expected output is 2014/09/26 when you provide 'yyyy-MM-dd' as date format?
To achieve your goal first convert $8 ( that is chararray when you load it) to date

```
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ToString(ToDate($8, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy/MM/dd') AS date;
```

Comment: but i am having huge row elements, how can i assign $8 as chararay ?

Comment: `STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/hl7' USING PigStorage('|');`
this line means that all rows loaded will be split by separator '|' to chararray fields as you didn;t specify schema. Just use the solution above and try to read more pig documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I am a beginner in pig Latin surely i'll follow your advice.

Comment: When i am putting this date in hive table and making the type as `date` it is making all the contents of date as null. Why it is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

```
MSH_DATA = FOREACH b GENERATE ToString(ToDate($7, 'yyyyMMdd','Asia/Kolkata'),'yyyy/MM/dd') AS date;
```

If you are working on the data from other country then you need to above code for time zone. (above example for working in India)

Comment: Thanks for the help